# How to read wav file as http response from android volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am writing android app that sends text to third party app and returns response as a wav audio data using android volley library. Has anybody done this ? I am unable to figure out how do I read the wav response and play the same in android media player

Comment: I am using nuance text to speech api